# The size of the vector in a Tree in C

Tags: c

So, I have to implement a B* Tree in C but I got some problems. I know this Tree is similar to B tree, but is necessary 2/3 full in a node instead 1/2. So when Im inserting in a root, for example with maximum 3 keys, and I need split I have this configuration

```
         B
     A      C
```

But it violates the proprieties.

So its necessary add +2 keys in the root ,but the internal nodes keep with 3 keys, and for this I need change the size of the vector and I don't know how to do that. Any help?

My struct

```
#define m 7
#define MAX_KEYS_LEAF  m - 1
#define MAX_KEYS m + 1
#define MAX_KIDS  m
#define MINIMUM  (2*m - 1)/3 -1

//B*TREE ESTRUTURA DA ÁRVORE

typedef struct tree {


int count;
int key[MAX_KEYS]; 
struct tree *kids[MAX_KIDS];
bool root;

} tree;
```

Comment: post your add-node code along with the error messages you are receiving.

Comment: Im not receiving an error, I just don't know how to start, in the first inserting I need a size of vector, and later I need other size. I just learned that is not possible change the size when its defined.

Comment: I already implemented the B tree, Im trying modify this code according to B*tree proprieties.